# Append URL with text from any clicked link

Tags: jquery

I have a table of part numbers.  My goal is to have the user click on the part number and have that part number populate into a form field on a separate page.  I have successfully accomplished this by appending the current page's URL with the clicked link text and then extrapolating it from the URL to populate the form field.  My issue is that I have only had success with inline "onclick" script.  I have hundreds of part numbers and putting the script on each line isn't ideal (or proper I imagine).  This is what I am currently doing to accomplish this task:

```
  onclick="location.href = $(this).attr('href')+ '?' +  $.trim($(this).text());return false"
```

How do I do this without the inline script?

I'm cobbling a website together for my family's business.  I'm not a professional - so please forgive my ignorance.  I'm extremely grateful for any assistance.

Comment: can you show the code for the whole line?

Comment: <tr><td>Adjusting Plate</td><td><a     href="Part_Inquiry.html"onclick="location.href = $(this).attr('href')+ '?' + $.trim($(this).text());return false">887B387G1</a></td></tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the script on each line in your javascript section you could add the following code:

```
$(function(){
    $('table a').on('click',function(){
      var url=$(this).attr('href')+'?'+$.trim($(this).text());
      $(this).attr('href',url);
    });
});
```

The jquery `$('table a')` is specific to only change the url if `a` in the table is clicked. Then you can create the url from the current `href` and append what you want and reset the href. However this will only change the current `href` of the element the user clicks and currently with `return false` you are stopping the user from progressing to the next page.

Comment: I'm certain that it's my ignorance but I cannot get your first solution to work.  It seems completely correct but the only way I can seem to get the URL on the next page to show (http://xxx/xxx/Part_Inquiry.html?887B387G1) is through the original inline method - including the return false.  Your second solution is way beyond my skill set - but I thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: how are you navigating to the next page with the href and return false?

Comment: ok if you use my code (1st example) and remove the onclick part in the table what does the console say or website do when you click on an element?

Comment: I removed all the inline code and placed your script at the bottom of the page.  the links just move on to the next page - nothing is appended, nothing is changed.  Again -I'm sure it's me.  Maybe my placement is wrong?  Maybe it's competing with something - I don't know enough to even troubleshoot this properly.  I really appreciate the help and patience.

Comment: what if you place the script at the top of the page and replace `$(document).read(function(){` with `$(function() {`

Comment: I moved it to the <head>, tried it with and without your changes - still nothing.

Comment: does the console say anything?

Comment: It's saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".  I got the same error when I tried your original script and the amended version without the $(document)...etc. part.

Comment: do you have something like this at the top of your source (above the jquery) `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I moved my src for the jquery above your original code and BAM - it worked!  You are spectacular. Thank you so, so much for the help and patience!  I am going to have to figure out how to execute the code for just the table elements though - would you mine sharing that with me?  It will take me days to figure it out.  You're the best!!!!

Comment: to only do links in the table change `$('a')` to `$('table a')`